# Flutter : unclear ValueChanged and FutureBuilder

Tags: flutter, future, setstate, flutter-futurebuilder

I'm getting some data from my API. I handle them by converting the returned JSON into some widget *CommentaireSingle*.

But there's something unclear for my, about the I guess the **build** method.

1. The *build* is called each time the widget is build, including the `setState` method.
2. The *FutureBuilder* is used to generate the content once it's fully loaded.
3. The *ValueChanged* is used to pass data from the children to it's parent.

So my question is : why each time that I do a `setState`, my *Future* is adding the original data to my view ? I have to clear the initial **listCommentsWidgets** is order to have the "logic" result (to not have twice the original list of widgets)

```
class _CommentairesListingState extends State<CommentairesListing> {
  List<Commentaire> listComments = [];
  Future loadListComments;
  List<Widget> listCommentsWidgets = [];

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    loadListComments = _loadComments();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return FutureBuilder(
      future: loadListComments,
      builder: (context, snapshot) {
        if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.done) {
          return generateComments();
        } else {
          return Center(
            child: SizedBox(
              height: 25,
              width: 25,
              child: CircularProgressIndicator(),
            ),
          );
        }
      },
    );
  }

  Future _loadComments() async {
    listComments = await MyWS()
        .getComs(widget.publication.pubId);
  }

  Expanded generateComments() {
    listCommentsWidgets.clear();
    for (Commentaire commentaire in listComments) {
      CommentaireSingle single = CommentaireSingle(
          ...
          toRemove: updateCommentaireListing, #ValueChanged
          responseTo: widget.responseTo);
      listCommentsWidgets.add(single);
    }

   Column column = Column(
      children: listCommentsWidgets,
    );

   return Expanded(
      child: Center(
        child: Container(
          width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width * 0.90,
          child: SingleChildScrollView(
            child: column,
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }

  void updateCommentaireListing(Commentaire commentaire) {
    setState(() {
      listComments.remove(commentaire);
      listCommentsWidgets.clear();
    });
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`setState` is called each time because it rebuilds your update ui. A Future can't listen to a variable change. It's a one-time response. Instead, you'll need to use a Stream if you will want to omit the setState call each time.

For removing list item duplication

```
Future _loadComments() async {
listComments = List(); // here add empty list for 
    listComments = await MyWS()
        .getComs(widget.publication.pubId);
  }
```

Comment: Why should I clear the *listComments* in the Future if _loadComments is called only in initState ? For what I understand, this seems to mean that the future is created once (initState), but rebuild each time (@build + FutureBuilder).

Comment: when you call `setState` it also called `initState` and then _loadComments comments called each time.

Comment: I thought `initstate` was call only once by screen